# get html notes from a list of titles using R

Tags: r, list, rest, class, web-scraping

I am trying to get information from individual projects from this webpage https://www.cif.org/projects. I know how to get the title and information for each individual project page, but I am struggling to find a way to generate a list of links to every project as appeared on the webpage

I would like to get the list of the html_nodes in order to iterate and get information from each project. I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3pFBp5oPU8&list=PLr5uaPu5L7xLEclrT0-2TWAz5FTkfdUiW&index=2
but I cannot get the list of the links

My code looks like this

```
link= "https://www.cif.org/projects"
page= read_html(link)
 main_title= page %>% html_nodes('.list-title') %>% html_text()
 main_title= page %>% html_nodes('.list-title') %>% html_attr("class") %>% paste("https://www.cif.org/projects", ., sep="")
```

I would like to get the HTML nodes

```
 <h3 class="list-title">DPSP Futures Window: Africa Go Green Fund</h3>\n
```

In order to create the individual link to the projects, that looks like this (an example from the first project): https://www.cif.org/projects/dpsp-futures-window-africa-go-green-fund.

But at the moment, this code only gives me this:

```
 "https://www.cif.org/projectslist-title"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to tune those selectors a bit. that same information is stored in several elements on the page, so you can choose those that are easiest to work with. When looking for links, you most likely want to collect `href` attributes of `a` elements:

```r
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www.cif.org/projects"
page <- read_html(link)

main_titles <- page %>% 
  html_elements("#ast-list-view a") %>% html_attr("title")
head(main_titles)
#> [1] "DPSP Futures Window: Africa Go Green Fund"                                                                                                                            
#> [2] "DPSP Futures Window: Green Shares - Eastern and Southern African Trade and Development Bank (TDB)"                                                                    
#> [3] "TAF: Scaling-Up Green and Sustainable Finance for Indonesia?s Energy Sector in Indonesia"                                                                             
#> [4] "TAF: Scaling-Up Green and Sustainable Finance for Indonesia’s Energy Sector in Indonesia"                                                                             
#> [5] "TAF: Support to integrating Corporate Climate Governance (CCG) into financial sector policies and building capacity of the financial sector in Kazakhstan and Morocco"
#> [6] "TAF: Support to integrating Corporate Climate Governance (CCG) into financial sector policies and building capacity of the financial sector in Kazakhstan and Morocco"

links <- page %>% 
  html_elements("#ast-list-view a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% 
  paste0("https://www.cif.org", .)
head(links)
#> [1] "https://www.cif.org/projects/dpsp-futures-window-africa-go-green-fund"                                                
#> [2] "https://www.cif.org/projects/dpsp-futures-window-green-shares-eastern-and-southern-african-trade-and-development-bank"
#> [3] "https://www.cif.org/projects/taf-scaling-green-and-sustainable-finance-indonesias-energy-sector-indonesia-0"          
#> [4] "https://www.cif.org/projects/taf-scaling-green-and-sustainable-finance-indonesias-energy-sector-indonesia"            
#> [5] "https://www.cif.org/projects/taf-support-integrating-corporate-climate-governance-ccg-financial-sector-policies-and-0"
#> [6] "https://www.cif.org/projects/taf-support-integrating-corporate-climate-governance-ccg-financial-sector-policies-and"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>